# In firefox, how do I create a bookmark and pin it to the taskbar as an icon, without it getting pinned to the firefox jump list

Tags: windows-7, firefox, taskbar, bookmarks

I have managed to successfully set this up by following a guide before, but that seems to have since disappeared from the internet.

If I recall correctly, it involved something as silly as creating shortcuts to shortcuts, or something along those lines.

I'm trying to make give myself an icon I can launch from the taskbar that will take me to a specific URL. If I create a normal shortcut and attempt to pin that, it instead gets pinned to the firefox jump list, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, found my own answer

http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-pin-a-website-link-to-windows-7-taskbar/

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the answer if it works.

Comment: Have to wait 2 days to do so by the looks of things! Thanks though.